# How can proxied image headers be modified on Apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, header, mod-proxy

We proxy images as licensed content and **need to add max-age headers to the proxied images**.  Attempted modifying `.htaccess`, but it didn't work and suspect this is due to the proxied image folder not being an actual directory on the server.

First, the proxy is set up in `apache2.conf`:

```
# Image Proxy
ProxyPass /photo http://photo.licensor.com
ProxyPassReverse /photo http://photo.licensor.com
```

Made several attempts to modify `.htaccess` under the site's public_html directory.  It appears that the condition to modify the max-age header for proxied images is never recognized by Apache since `/photo` is not a real directory.

I'd really like to target ONLY the proxied images using the `/photo` directory that isn't real.

Comment: `<Location /photo/>  
   Header unset Etag  
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"      Header unset Expires
</Location>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a `<location>` container in an htaccess file. It's probably best to put this in your apache server config file next to your `ProxyPass` settings:

```
<LocationMatch "/photo">
  # Image Proxy
  ProxyPass http://photo.licensor.com
  ProxyPassReverse http://photo.licensor.com
  Header unset Etag 
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public" 
  Header unset Expires
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: After implementing your code in apache2.conf I received the following from apache:
`Syntax error on line 57 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location.
Action 'configtest' failed.`

Comment: @fantisy sorry, you need to remove the `/photo` part from the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` lines